# Unable to locate package libopencv-dev

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I'm running 12.04 desktop on a persistence USB pendrive. I Googled around, but answers say something like:

> Ubuntu 12.04 provides a package of OpenCV 2.3.1 that you can easily
>   install by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
> ```

But it does not work for me.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libopencv-dev
```

The following commands each returned successful results:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366267/error-given-installing-opencv-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That package is available from the [Universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libopencv-dev), if `apt` can't find it this probably means you are missing that repo in your sources.

Take a look at the sources file:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And make sure it includes these lines

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe   
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise restricted main multiverse universe

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe  
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe
```

Note that to change this file you'll need root permissions, e.g.:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After adding these lines run `apt-get update` and try to install the package again.